# google cloud no healthy upstream instance group

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

So I have setup a instance group and have had a random error ( which happens randomly without cause ) pop up saying `no healthy upstream` I am using a reserved IP for the load balancing I then use aws route 53 A record to route traffic to said IP.

The only thing that seems to fix it is going to the actual IP `static IP` then actually go to the domain although this is unsustainable in production. I can post my full steps if needed but has anyone else had this problem and know a fix? This is a subdomain btw and using HTTPS which is included in the load balancer with the actual certificate